# (SpringBoot) Problem in JunitTest can't use @Mockbeans on a list of subclasses

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito, autowired, spring-test

I have a specific problem in my unit tests.

in my service I use a @Autowired to get a list of all my subclasses.
Example :

```
@Autowired
List<MotherRepositoryClass> repositories;
```

So in my service I have a list of all subclasses that are automatically instantiated and it's working fine.

However I want to do the same thing to mock them in my tests to avoid adding for each class an attribute.  Unfortunately the @Mockbean annotation is only available for one bean.

For now, the only track I found was to put the same attribute @Autowire with my MotherClass and mocking them inside a `@BeforeEach`. However the Mockito.mock() is not the same as the @Mockbean as it only mock the provided instance so the service instantiate a new Bean when created.

EDIT 1 : I may do something with the ApplicationContext

Comment: You can try use `@MockBean({ ParentMotherRepositoryClass.class, ParentOfParentMotherRepositoryClass.class)` on the class level of your test. It will create mocks for your repository beans, and you can easily  use `@Autowired List` in your test

Comment: The thing is that my MotherRepository is just an interface and I don't have a parent for this

Comment: And when I just put my mother class it says that multiple beans have been found but only one can be replaced

Comment: You Should declare in `@MockBean` classes which are implements your `MotherRepository`

Comment: I see but in this case I will have to specify all the classes, my goal is to avoid to edit my UT when I create a new implementation of my mother class. So it can Mock all the instantiated beans of the context like a @Autowired but for mocking them.